# How to restart a pygame game with user input and also keep record of score?

Tags: python, file, pygame, restart, 2d-games

I have made a game HANGMAN. I want to restart the game with user input if they want to. I have many fuctions so while loops would not work. I have to keep the record of the score also. I have also variables which need to be reset. Like this one.

```
word = random.choice(words.final_words).upper()
```

It choose a word from a huge list of words. That list is in another file named words.py.

```
hangman_status = 6
```

This tells at which stage the hangman is. It need to be reset to 0.

There are many variables like this.

This is the whole code if you are intersted to see.

```
import pygame, math, random, words

# setup display
pygame.init()
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hangman')


# load images
images = []
for i in range(7):
    image = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\hp\Pygame\Hangman\hangman' + str(i) + '.png')
    images.append(image)


# colours
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)


# game variables
hangman_status = 0
word = random.choice(words.final_words).upper()
guessed = []


# fonts
LETTER_FONT = pygame.font.Font(r'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts\Azonix.otf', 30)
WORD_FONT = pygame.font.Font(r'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts\Azonix.otf', 35)
RESULT_FONT = pygame.font.Font(r'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts\Azonix.otf', 45)

# button variables
RADIUS = 20
GAP = 15
let_pos = []
startx = round((WIDTH - (GAP + RADIUS * 2) * 13) / 2)
starty = 380
A = 65
for i in range(26):
    x = startx + GAP * 2 + ((RADIUS * 2 + GAP) * (i % 13))
    y = starty + ((i // 13) * (GAP + RADIUS * 2))
    let_pos.append([x, y, chr(A + i), True])



# setup game loop
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True


# draw
def draw():
    win.fill(WHITE)
    text = RESULT_FONT.render('Hangman', 1, BLACK)
    win.blit(text, (int(WIDTH/2) - int(text.get_width()/2), 20))

    # draw word
    display_word = ""
    for letter in word:
        if letter in guessed:
            display_word += letter + ' '
        else:
            display_word += '_ '
    text = WORD_FONT.render(display_word, 1, BLACK)
    win.blit(text, (340, 200))

    # draw buttons
    for letter in let_pos:
        x, y, ltr, visible = letter
        if visible:
            pygame.draw.circle(win, BLACK, (x, y), RADIUS, 2)
            text = LETTER_FONT.render(ltr, 1, BLACK)
            win.blit(text, (x - int(text.get_width()/2), y - int(text.get_height()/2)))


    win.blit(images[hangman_status], (100, 80))
    pygame.display.update()

# display  word
def last_word():
    win.fill(BLACK)
    text = RESULT_FONT.render(f'The word was: {word}', 1, WHITE)
    win.blit(text, (int(WIDTH/2 - int(text.get_width()/2)), int(HEIGHT/2) - int(text.get_height()/2)))
    pygame.display.update()

# result
def display_message(message):
    win.fill(BLACK)
    text = RESULT_FONT.render(message, 5, WHITE)
    win.blit(text, (int(WIDTH/2) - int(text.get_width()/2), int(HEIGHT/2) - int(text.get_height()/2)))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(3000)

# game loop

while run:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    draw()
    # events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            m_x, m_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            for letter in let_pos:
                x, y, ltr, visible = letter
                if visible:
                    dis = math.sqrt((m_x- x)**2 + (m_y - y)**2)
                    if dis <= RADIUS:
                        letter[3] = False
                        guessed.append(ltr)
                        if ltr not in word:
                            hangman_status += 1
    won = True
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in guessed:
            won = False

    # check if the player lost won
    if won:
        last_word()
        pygame.time.delay(2000)
        display_message('You WON!')
        break

    # check if the player lost
    if hangman_status == 6:
        pygame.time.delay(1000)
        last_word()
        pygame.time.delay(4000)
        display_message('You Lost.')
        break

pygame.quit()
print(' '.join(word.split(' ')).title())
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make your entire game/round run inside a function?
You could pass in whatever arguments you need to.

eg:

```py
def game_round():
    # Preset initial vars if not passing to func:
    total_score = 0
    while run:
        # Have run_game return score and a bool indicating user wants to restart/not.
        round_score, restart = run_game()
        if restart:
            total_score = 0
            # Whatever variables you want to reset, do this here too
        else:
            total_score += round_score
```

Comment: I see this answer has been upvoted. If it helped solve your question, accepting the answer would be helpful to others.